# how to convert array of json to array of java bean using Gson

Tags: java, gson

I'm having String of array of json objects

```
String jarray=  "{
                    "jsonarray": [{
                        "row_id": "2",
                        "priorty_seq": "1",
                        "id": "2",

                    }, {
                        "row_id": "1",
                        "priorty_seq": "1",
                        "id": "3",

                    }, {
                        "row_id": "0",
                        "priorty_seq": "1",
                        "iid": "1",

                        "is_active_html": "<i class='fa fa-lg fa-warning' style='color:red'></i>&nbsp;<b>Inactive</b>"
                    }, {
                        "row_id": "6",
                        "priorty_seq": "1",
                        "id": "64",

                    }]
                    }";
```

This is array string, now i have to map this with  java bean

```
class JavaBean
       { 
         @SerializedName("row_id") String row_id;
         @SerializedName("priorty_seq")String priorty_seq;
         @SerializedName("id")String id ;   
        }
```

Now what i'm trying to do is map this json object to List of Javabean
 do we have any method that directly map those to list of bean instead 
of mapping them to json abject and iterate over json array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can get rid of the "jsonarray" key and just keep the array itself you can easily solve this with the following piece of code;

```
String jarray = "[" +
                "{id: '1', priorty_seq: '10', row_id: '100'}," +
                "{id: '2', priorty_seq: '20', row_id: '200'}," +
                "{id: '3', priorty_seq: '30', row_id: '300'}" +
                "]";
Type type = new TypeToken<Collection<JavaBean>>() {}.getType();
Collection<JavaBean> result = new Gson().fromJson(jarray, type);
```

Source: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Array-Examples